# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then their Spearman's Correlation Coefficient is...?

Tags: correlation, independence, spearman-rho

I have often seen the following statement:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then their 'correlation' is $0$

What is meant by 'correlation'? Is it specific to measures of *linear* correlation? Or does this claim apply to *non-linear* measures of correlation, as well?  (e.g. if $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables, then their Spearman's Correlation Coefficient is...?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This typically means Pearson correlation. While zero Pearson correlation is insufficient to conclude that two variables are independent (think of a [parabolic relationship like I show here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/582503/247274)), a nonzero correlation means dependence.

However, it applies to all types of correlation. If *independence* is to have a reasonable definition in probability theory (which I believe it does), then knowing something about one variable should tell you nothing about the other. For Spearman correlation in particular, if variables are independent, then knowing that one variable takes a high value should not tell you that the other is particularly likely to take a high value (or a low value for Spearman correlation less than zero).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you please clarify what you mean by "...it applies to all types of correlation"? It's not clear to me if you are saying that there exist certain types of correlation (presumably non-linear) measures that *can*, in fact, produce non-zero values for two independent random variables.

Comment: @FrightenedofSinusoids: I would say that if you define some new correlation measure $\text{MyNewGlouriosCorrelation}$  which turns out **not** to be zero for independent variables, I would scrap that new measure!  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534454/a-formal-definition-of-a-measure-of-association/535771#535771

Answer (score 1):

Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables. Let $r()$ be the rank transformation. Then the Spearman correlation is the same as the Pearson correlation of the ranks, that is, of $r(X), r(Y)$.

Since [Functions of Independent Random Variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/functions-of-independent-random-variables) are independent, $r(X)$ and $r(Y)$ are independent, so their Pearson correlation is zero, which is to say that the Spearman correlation of $X$ and $Y$ is zero.