# Show that $E [u] = 0$ and $cov(u,x_j)=0$ does not imply $E[u|x]=0$

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, exogeneity

In the regression model
$$y= x'\beta + u, \quad x = (1, x_2,...,x_K)$$
with
$$E[u |x]=0,$$

we know that it implies: $E [u] = 0$ and $cov(u,x_j)=0$, for $j=1,...,K$.

I think that the reciprocal is not true. Thinking geometrically, they seem equivalent, but I can't come up with a counterexample!

Do you have a counterexample?

**Thinking geometrically**

Defining $\langle X,Y\rangle= E[XY]$ we have that if $X$ or $Y$ is such that $E[X]=0$ or $E[Y]=0$, we have:
$$\langle X,Y\rangle=cov(X,Y)$$
So, if $cov(u,x_j)=0$, I have orthoganility: $\langle u,x_j\rangle=0$ for all $j=1,...,k$. This seems to imply that the projection of $u$ onto $1,x_2,...,x_k$ is $0$, i.e. $E[u|x]=0$.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190703/non-linear-endogeneity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to contrive counterexamples is to let $X$ follow some (non-degenerate) distribution symmetric about $0$ and choose $c \in \mathbb R_{>0}$ s.t. $U \mathrel{:=} X^b - c$ has expectation $0$ for an even number $b \neq 0$.

Then, symmetry of the distribution of $X$ about $0$ [implies](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/582292/136579) $\mathrm{Cov}(X,U) = 0$, and we have $\mathbb E(U) = 0$ and $\mathbb E(U \,|\, X) = X^b - c$ by construction.

An easy example that comes to my mind is $X \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and $U \mathrel{:=} X^2 - 1$.

Comment: Clever example. +1.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

\begin{align}
P(U=-1, X=0)& = 1/2\\
P(U=1, X=1) &= 1/4\\
P(U=1, X=-1) &= 1/4
\end{align}

Comment: Would very much appreciate how you contrived the example or the approach to construct the same.

Comment: @User1865345 Almost any two distributions with 0 covariance and E(X)=0 will do. The first 2 lines can be anything, e.g. `P(U=3, X=10) = 0.1, P(U=16,X=17) = 0.2`. Then you just solve the simultaneous equation `Cov(U, X) = 0; E(x) = 0` to find the third line `P(U=-5,X=16.4) = 0.7`. This will result in a valid counterexample unless you are very unlucky.

Comment: This is indeed a good approach. I would urge to add this to the answer.

Comment: Dear, does your example have to do with a linear regression model with a constant regressor?